What's the oldest software or algorithm still in general usage in its original form?
With all the focus on new tech, I was wondering what the oldest tool or algorithm still in general usage is. The oldest that I've seen so far is the diff algorithm, from 1986, based on a paper by Eugene Myers. I'm not thinking of things like COBOL or C, which have changed to reflect the times, but those that have remained essentially unchanged since they were introduced.

IDK what's the oldest, but the Euclid's Algorithm that we use today dates back to 1844. (The original Euclid's algorithm was first published in 300BC.) I wouldn't be surprised to hear of others whose modern form is even older.

If you're looking for an algorithm that was invented specifically to be used in computing machinery, then it's got to be at least as old as CORDIC—1956.

This question doesn't make sense. Is a half-adder an algorithm? A counter? A stack? Is Pythagoras' Theorem an algorithm? Gaussian Elimination is surely an algorithm.

P.S., Voting to close as "opinion based." Technically speaking, you are asking for a fact—what's the oldest? But, you're inviting debate about what counts as an "algorithm," what counts as "still in general usage," whether or not the present form really is or is not equivalent to the version published on such-and-such date," etc.

For some meaning of "original form", Newton's algorithms (early XVIII century) may qualify.

I would say counting is the oldest still in use - can't think of many programs that don't count at some point :)) On a side note, when asking fundamental questions, one would need to make very clear what base definitions are, right? Merriam Webster say an algorithm is "broadly : a step-by-step procedure for solving a problem or accomplishing some end".  One-plus-one-plus-one is a problem that existed and has been solved in prehistoric times - like for counting sheep in the morning to check for losses - and still relevant - like counting search results :)))

This question doesn't seem to know that an 'algorithm' does not require a computer. It doesn't even have to be a mathematical or logical operation.

The OP is 'staff'. Looks like some sort of ill-advised attempt to stimulate discussion on a number of SE forums.

The way Stone Age people dissected an animal could already be an algorithm.

@dave I'm trying to get community input on some work in progress.

@dave, Re, "...doesn't...have to be...mathematical..." Maybe not in modern use, but the origins of the word, "algorithm," trace back to the name of a Persian mathematician, Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi. At first, "algorithm" referred specifically to pencil-and-paper techniques for adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing numbers written in decimal, place-value notation. It was his treatise on Hindu mathematics that brought those techniques to the attention of European scholars.
